# Opposite/inverted scroll onScroll with jQuery

Tags: jquery, scroll, scrolltop

I want to make a page that scrolls down normally on the left div, but scrolls inverted (up) on the right div.
However it does not start the scroll on the right when I start the scroll on the left.
When I scroll it only scrolls the left for some length, and then it starts scrolling as expected.

http://jsbin.com/orole3/36/edit

What am I doing wrong?

----------------------Javascript----------------------

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#two').scrollTop($('#two')[0].scrollHeight);
   $('#one').scroll(function(){
     var length = $(this).scrollTop();
     $('#two').scrollTop((two.scrollHeight)-length);
   });
});
```

----------------------Html----------------------

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<!--[if IE]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<style>
  #one, #two{
    float: left;
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="one">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
  <div id="two">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please include your source code in the post as well as your jsbin link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84342/answer-that-only-contains-a-link-to-jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   var height = $('#two')[0].scrollHeight;

   $('#two').scrollTop(height);

   height = $("#two").scrollTop();

   $('#one').scroll(function(){
     var length = $(this).scrollTop();

     console.log(height);
     console.log(length);

     $('#two').scrollTop(height - length);

   });
});
```

the `scrollHeight` actually does not equal to `scrollTop()`.

http://jsbin.com/orole3/43/edit

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#two').scrollTop($('#two').height());
  var offset = $("#two").height() - $('#two').scrollTop();
   $('#one').scroll(function(){
     var length = $("#one").scrollTop();
     $('#two').scrollTop($('#two').innerHeight()-length-offset);
   });
});
```